# How to use bundler (0.9.1.pre1) with Rails and CouchRest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchdb, bundler

I want to use the current version of [bundler](http://github.com/carlhuda/bundler) (there have been quite some changes from 0.8 to 0.9) to mange the gems of my Rails app. First I created a `Gemfile` in the root of the app folder and added all the needed gems to it. Then I placed (as recommended in the manual) the following code to my `config/environment.rb`:

```
begin
  # Require the preresolved locked set of gems.
  require File.expand_path('../.bundle/environment', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
  # Fallback on doing the resolve at runtime.
  require "rubygems"
  require "bundler"
  Bundler.setup
end
```

`bundle install` seems to work fine as it finished with `Your bundle is complete!`. But when starting my app I get the following error:

```
$ ruby script/server  
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant CouchRest (NameError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
        from /home/kuf/data/Arbeit/Decodon/2009-05-08-Project_Orange/orangemix/fuse/config/initializers/couchdb.rb:35
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
         ... 11 levels...
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from script/server:3
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is it you have in your `Gemfile` ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Damien. True, I should have given that information, too. Luckily I found the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrrg, just pushed the send button and had an idea that solved the problem. The bundler manual says: "[...] include the following at the beginning of your code." For a Rails app you have to put the mentioned part at the bottom of `config/environment.rb` to get everything setup correctly before:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION

require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'boot')

Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
...
end

# Put the bundler related stuff here!
begin
  # Require the preresolved locked set of gems.
  require File.expand_path('../.bundle/environment', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
  # Fallback on doing the resolve at runtime.
  require "rubygems"
  require "bundler"
  Bundler.setup
end
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I was trying to get this working last week with complete failure. I was putting the bundler initialization code BEFORE the Rails initializer though. I ended up switching back to bundler 0.8.1, which is better documented (right now) with Rails 2.3.5.

Comment: Glad this helped you, too. Currently most of the documentation around is for pre 0.9 and much has changed. Hope this will change soon.

Comment: You should accept your answer now, so this stops showing up in the list of unanswered.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but stackoverflow prevents the acceptance of an own answers for 2 days. Now it's possible.